# How to send an Object as JSON to a Server using NameValuePairs?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, basicnamevaluepair

I am attempting to add some `Book(title, author, year)` into my `book` table in a server using an `AsyncTask`, but i am getting `missing bookobject as JSON`from the method `addBook`(from the server). So i made a `bookObject` like this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("title", "JAVA");
jObj.put("author", "me");
jObj.put("year", 2005);
```

After that, i wanna use(my intention is to send this book `Object`):

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(jObj));        //Error
new AaaBookAsyncTask(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
```

The problem is `BasicNameValuePair`cannot applied to `JSONObject`, but now how can i send the book `Object`? - Any help or hints is very appreciated.Thanks, Carl

Answer (score 0):

You could send the JSON as a string and then decode it on your server before storing it in your database.

Comment: I tried this. For example `String json = gson.toJson(book)` but i get the same message: `missing bookobject as JSON`. Therfor i'm thinking simply to send the `Object`. In addition to that i can't reach the server/method inside it. I get just a messge ok or not!